# Upload multiple files using flask and read as variable

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I have a python script that reads content of 2 files, and maps the data and outputs a csv. Currently the code reads the path of the files however I want it so that the user uploads the file and the code reads the files and generates the csv.

I started the flask code that uploads the multiple files but I need help saving the files to variables that my python script would be able to read.

My python script:

```
user_input = input("Enter the path of First File : ")
user_input2 = input("Enter the path of Second File : ")
assert os.path.exists(user_input), "Invalid file at, " + str(user_input)
f = open(user_input, 'r')
f2 = open(user_input2, 'r')
content = f.read()
content2 = f2.read()

def parse_value(txt):
    reclines = []
    for line in txt.split('\n'):
        if ':' not in line:
            if reclines:
                yield reclines
                reclines = []
        else:
            reclines.append(line)

def parse_fields(reclines):
    res = {}
    for line in reclines:
        key, val = line.strip().rstrip(',').split(':', 1)
        res[key.strip()] = val.strip()
    return res

res = []
for rec in parse_value(content):
    res.append(parse_fields(rec))    

res2 = []
for rec in parse_value(content2):
    res2.append(parse_fields(rec))    

df = pd.json_normalize(res)
df2 = pd.json_normalize(res2)
```

flask codes for uploading files:

```
upload.py

import os
import magic
from app import app
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['tpi'])

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/')
def upload_form():
    return render_template('button.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
        if request.method == 'POST':
                print(request.__dict__)
        # check if the post request has the file part
                if 'sfile' not in request.files:
                        flash('No file part')
                        return redirect(request.url)
                file = request.files['sfile']
                if file.filename == '':
                        flash('No file selected for uploading')
                        return redirect(request.url)
                if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
                        flash('File successfully uploaded')
                        return redirect('/')
                else:
                        flash('Allowed file types are tpi')
                        return redirect(request.url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port = 5000, debug=True)
```

button.html

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Python Flask File Upload Example</title>
<h2>Upload First File</h2>
<form method="post" name="sform" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <dl>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="sfile" autocomplete="off" required>
        </p>
    </dl>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="ssubmit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>
<h2>Upload Second File</h2>
<form method="post" name="wform" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <dl>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="sfile" autocomplete="off" required>
        </p>
    </dl>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="wsubmit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>
```

How can I fix the flask codes to save the first uploaded file to variable f and and second uploaded variable to f2?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `.read()` method.

```
with open(user_input, 'r') as file:
    file_one = file.read()

with open(user_input, 'r') as file:
    file_two = file.read()
```

You may need to instantiate the file vars outside the context manager, but [something like this should get you started](https://pythontect.com/how-to-read-text-file-into-string-variable-in-python/#:%7E:text=The%20read%20text%20can%20be%20stored%20into%20a,which%20do%20not%20requires%20to%20close%20file%20explicitly.)